# Apply bold font to two consecutive rows in a datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, fonts

I have two consecutive rows in a datagridview, both of which need to be bold. I have changed the text colour for the lower row to red as follows. Although I can't seem to find a similar bold function.

`cashBookRowsMarchTotals.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the two rows bold using the following code, but was wondering if it is possible to apply bold (or other styles) to multiple rows/columns at a time?

`cashBookRowsMarchTotals.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(cashBookRowsMarchTotals.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            cashBookRowsMarchTotals.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(cashBookRowsMarchTotals.Font, FontStyle.Bold);`

Comment: You cannot change font style for particular rows or columns in default DataGridView. Use custom GridView

Answer (score 0):

I saw your answer and I feel like let you know about the **CellFormatting** Event of the **dataGridView**.  It is actually built to format the dataGridView based from the row index or column values.

This code example changes the font based on the value of a column but you can easily change it to filter by the row index instead of the column value.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the color of the row if the value on column1 is > 0
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value) > 0)  // Column1
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;  // Set font color red
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);   // Set Bold   
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == (int)transactionsDGV.AmountDue && Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value) <= 0)  // Column Amount Due
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;  // Set font color black  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Poperty of **DataGridView**

**RowsDefaultCellStyle** Click on Ellipse [**...**] and Set the **Font** Properties