# C# Change Specific Row Font of Data Grid View

Tags: c#, datagridview, fonts

I tried to change font with this code:
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

This didn't work, only way font would change was by changing RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font.
I guess Row Template overrides my changes. I was also trying to change font in Form's constructor.
extra info: row and column headers visibility are set to false and user is not allowed to add more rows or delete or resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visit the like [Apply bold font to two consecutive rows in a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290300/apply-bold-font-to-two-consecutive-rows-in-a-datagridview)

```
dg1.AllowUserToAddRows=true;
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser, link had what i needed. Event CellFormating can change CellStyle of any cell while constructor of Form can't. I guess it's order of thing. Row Template will format cells so only changing Row Template worked in constructor. Thanks a lot.